# iOS orientation issue with external display

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I have made simple SingleViewApplication and added a label. Problem is the external display which is supposed to be in landscape but its in portrait, so whatever i do my app is in sideways as shown in picture. I have tried landscape orientation as well as portrait orientation.

Any thoughts on this.
[image]

Comment: Was getting an error. Its added now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by setting device orientation as Landscape and retuned NO in shouldAutoRatate